# On the Get Satisfaction website, how do I see more than the last 15 replies?

Tags: getsatisfaction.com

We have seen this message:

> Due to volume, only the 15 most recent replies are being displayed

There doesn't appear to be any official way to show more.

Is there a backdoor way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this information;

http://getsatisfaction.com/getsatisfaction/topics/see_all_replies_on_high_volume_topics

Including a link to here;

[http://thormuller.com/long_topics/show.php?topic=[TOPIC_SLUG]](http://thormuller.com/long_topics/show.php?topic=%5bTOPIC_SLUG%5d)

> Where TOPIC_SLUG is the topic name as it appears in the Topic URL

Hope this helps.